# how to create sqlalchemy table class from app class

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have my app built and working and I´d like to use a database through SQLAlchemy.
Is there a way to create the table mapping from my classes? I´ve searched everywhere but just found the other way around.

This is a example of what I want.

```py
@dataclass
class User:
    name: str
    grade: float
    age: int

users_table= sqlalchemyfacility(User)
mapper(User, users_table)
metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Does SQLAlchemy provide such a "sqlalchemyfacility"?